# Check if file exists on public remote ftp server

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to check if a file exists on a public FTP server

`ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-100/tsv/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.entrez.tsv.gz`

I tried to use `url-exists` like so but without success.

```
var urlExists = require('url-exists');
url1 = 'ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-100/tsv/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.entrez.tsv.gz'
urlExists(url1, function(err, exists) {
    console.log(url1)
    console.log(exists); // false
});
```

This does work for http urls

```
var urlExists = require('url-exists');
url1 = 'https://www.google.com/'
urlExists(url1, function(err, exists) {
    console.log(url1)
    console.log(exists); // true
});
```

Comment: url exists works on http only

Comment: Understood. Just proving that I wasn't being a lazy SO bum. How do I check if the file exists on the ftp server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah FTP is not HTTP, your seeing it work in the browser as the browser can handle the ftp protocol.

---

If your targeting that specific ftp site, you can replace the `ftp://` with `http://` as they are also serving it over HTTP

For example:

`http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-100/tsv/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.100.entrez.tsv.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Unless the ftp is open and no authentication is needed. I’d recommend to use some npm package for communicating with the ftp server. Actually even is no auth is needed you moght have to establish a connection to the server.

Like suggested by Lawrence Cherone above. Most modern FTP servers supprr some HTTP integration and changing the URL protocol prefix from
FTP to HTTP(S) should do the trick

Checkout - this post - [Node.js connect to ftp and download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437453/node-js-connect-to-ftp-and-download-files/44437646) which recommends this package
https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp

Establish a connection and use the available API to search for the file.

Lastly I’d recommend to read the post about the difference between FTP and HTTP(S) protocols
[Access FTP via HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554435/access-ftp-via-http)

Comment: The ftp server is open. If you copy-paste the ftp url, you can download the file. Does that change your answer at all?